# Preventing similar POST requests with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, ngresource, angular-http-interceptors

I am currently building a dashboard page with multiple widgets. Those widgets retrieve their data with REST calls ($resource). A few widgets make similar calls and I don't want to DDOS our server so I am looking for a way to make a call only once and resolve all similar requests with the same response.

Since I am restricted to using POST requests only, I cannot use the cache option that $resource offers. This seems to be doing exactly what I want but only for GET requests.

I was thinking along the lines of using a http interceptor to queue similar POST requests, fire only one of them and resolving them all when the first one gets its response.

However, I cannot seem to put the pieces together so any help is appreciated. I am open to other options.

Kind regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Services in AngularJS are singletons, so a solution would be to store the response in the service, as a variable. Then next time you'll do the request, previously check if the variable is null, if it's not you wrap it in a promise and returned it. If it's null, then you do the request, and store the response for the next call.

You can also either use this in your request service or in your interceptor service.

I hope I helped !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I would like to take it a step further, since this solution will still make 4 calls if 4 widgets are on the same page and the cache isn't populated yet.

I would like something that Angular does for GET requests. Comments from their source code:

If there are multiple GET requests for the same URL that should be cached using the same cache, but the cache is not populated yet, only one request to the server will be made and the remaining requests will be fulfilled using the response from the first request.

Comment: @TimKetelaars the trick is to cache the promise and not the result. If your question is about this pattern specifically let me know and I'll add the answer.

Comment: I managed to cache the similar promises in an array and resolve all of them once the initial one is resolved. However, I have only been able to do this in a service but would like this to land in an interceptor. I don't know how to combine this, since the request method of the $httpProvider interceptor does not return a promise but a config object. On a sidenote: is the interceptor the right place to implement this?

Comment: Hi Tim, did you end up with a solution ? I would love to see a snippet of code ! For the interceptor, I don't know, it seems to me that it is the right place, but I haven't a clear idea of how to do it. Maybe you could try to combine the $httpProvider.request method to intercept and the $httpProvider.response method to send a result back. Good luck mate !

Comment: I went with the service method for now. The idea was to use the $httpProvider methods you mentioned but haven't figured out a way to do this yet. Snippet:`
`var similarRequests = null;

function getData(requestData) {
 var deferred = $q.defer();

 if (similarRequests === null) {
  similarRequests = new Array();
  aService.getData(requestData).then(function (data) {
   deferred.resolve(data);
   angular.forEach(similarRequests, function (request) {
    request.resolve(data);
   });
   similarRequests = null;
  });
 } else {
  similarRequests.push(deferred);
 }

 return deferred.promise;
};`

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your widgets to depend on a service (singleton). 
This service should either poll the server via XHR, or get server push via websocket for updates.

If polling, look into server side caching and etags.